# There is no "may be used uninitialized" when optimization is disabled

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

In simple short words:

I need to show "may be used uninitialized" for -O0 optimization

I have problem with cause warning "may be used uninitialized in this function" when optimization is turned off.

I have in code something like this:

```
 int i = i;
```

Which is obviously wrong. And if compiler optimization is turned off - there is no warning but if I turn optimization to -O1 warring appears.

I need to show this warning when optimizations by -O option are disabled.

Ofcourse there are gcc warning options:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Wuninitialized -Werror
```

I read chapter [3.10 Options That Control Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), turn off optimization and manually add all -f flags which should be turned on for -O1 level:

```
-fauto-inc-dec          
-fcprop-registers           
-fdce           
-fdefer-pop           
-fdelayed-branch           
-fdse           
-fguess-branch-probability           
-fif-conversion2           
-fif-conversion           
-fipa-pure-const           
-fipa-reference           
-fmerge-constants
-fsplit-wide-types           
-ftree-builtin-call-dce           
-ftree-ccp           
-ftree-ch           
-ftree-copyrename           
-ftree-dce           
-ftree-dominator-opts           
-ftree-dse           
-ftree-forwprop           
-ftree-fre           
-ftree-phiprop           
-ftree-sra           
-ftree-pta           
-ftree-ter           
-funit-at-a-time
```

and additional:

```
-fdefer-pop
-fthread-jumps
-fcprop-registers
-fomit-frame-pointer
```

There is no warning.

Please, could you tell me which flag I missed?
Compiler which I must use is gcc-4.5.4

Comment: IIRC the unused code warnings are generated by the GCC branch/code elimination pass. Since no such pass is performed at `-O0`, no unused code warnings appear. Why do you insist on using `-O0`, anyway?

Comment: I don't think there is any way around this - you'll need to use your "release" build with optimisations enabled in order to catch uninitialised variable problems.

Comment: That gcc is old, can you update to 4.9.1 or newer?

Comment: Works on 4.9.0 with warnings enabled: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9526e7a9969f6a3 perhaps this is version dependent.

Comment: @Surt: I *think* that all GCC versions behave the same way. Most of GCC, including the inline assembler, is disabled at `-O0`.  `-O0` is marginally useful for debugging, but that's all.

Comment: @thkala, you are most likely right, but there is some point where the compiler changes to be more C++11 than C++03 and a changed behaviour could happen. But now there is what appear to be an right answer below.

Comment: I need -O0 optimization for debug version which is used to verify code by gerrit and - in this case release version fails but development version works pretty well without warnings. I can't used newer version because this is ARM cross compiler provided by vendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need:

> `-Wuninitialized -Winit-self`

for that one. Even with `-O0`, that still generates a warning about self initialisation (at least for gcc 4.7.2):

```
pax> cat x.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int i = i;
    return 0;
}

pax> gcc -O0 -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -o x x.c
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:4:6: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

---

If you *can't* get this happening for your version of `gcc`, there *may* be another way. You could change the way you build things so that checks are done first at `-O1` and only if they pass do you proceed to do the `-O0` build. A `Makefile` like this should be a good start:

```
x: x.c
    gcc -O1 -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Werror -o x x.c
    gcc -O0 -o x x.c
```

The first compilation will treat warnings as errors so, if it finds self initialisation, the `make` process will stop completely.

If there are no warnings, you carry on and build the executable again but with `-O0`.

That may need tuning to make it so only self initialisation stops the process and they may be a little trickier. But it's something to keep in mind if you need the behaviour and you can't convince your current compiler to give it to you at that optimisation level.

One way would be to simply *not* use `-Werror` but instead capture the output of the compiler and search specifically for the string `is used uninitialized`, returning an error code to your `make` process. That's a bit of a kludge but you may end up having to do something of that description.

Comment: @Tyrreus, try it with my minimal code and the command exactly as I've shown. If it's still not warning, I'd consider upgrading to a newer compiler if possible (if you _really_ need this feature).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't upgrade gcc because it's vendor provided ARM cross compiled toolchain.

Comment: @Tyrreus Then there is no solution to your problem. The only way to get your gcc version to emit the warning is to increase the optimization level.

Comment: @paxdiablo "You could change the way you build things so that checks are done first at -O1 and only if they pass do you proceed to do the -O0 build. A Makefile like this should be a good start" - it looks like sufficient workaround. Thanks.

Comment: I'd change the output of the second command to `-o x.gerrit`. Except for this "gerrit" tool there seems to be no valid reason to have an `-O0` build anyway.